# Get HTML's <TD> Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to get the static values from my table data (the  tag) and and display it to another page. Should I use jQuery for this or possibly PHP?

Example.php Table:

```
                                <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover display" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Race</th>
                                        <th>Role</th>
                                        <th>2015</th>
                                        <th>2016</th>
                                        <th>2017</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="Testing">
                                        <td>BLAH</td>
                                        <td>ANOTHA_BLAH</td>
                                        <td>25</td>
                                        <td>26</td>
                                        <td>27</td>
                                    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried doing it in PHP similar to

```
       <form action = "PutTheExampleTableValuesHere.php" method = "post">
           TABLE BLAH BLAH BLAH
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Line Chart">
```

and using the $_POST function and simply echoing it to the other pages but my logic failed.

Please guide. Thank you!

Comment: You can insert a `textarea` tag inside the `form` tag and enter the code for the static table inside it. This way, your form, when submitted, will `POST` that information to your `action`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use AJAX to post the whole html code to the other page (`URL`):

```
$.post(URL, {data: encodeURIComponent($("#dataTables-example").html())})
```

On the other page(`URL`), you can use php's `$_POST` to get it:

```
<form action = "PutTheExampleTableValuesHere.php" method = "post">
    <table ...>
        <?php urldecode($_POST['data']) ?>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Line Chart">
```

UPDATE:
@SimoneWalter Then you can compose the `data` in `$.post` with the TD values. For example:

```
data = []
$.each($("#dataTables-example TR"), function(tr){
    // get td values
    tmp = []
    $.each($(tr).find('TD'), function(td){
        tmp.push($(td).html())
    })
    data.push(tmp)
})
// post the data
// data will be something like:
// [['Race', 'Role', '2015', ...], ...]
$.post(URL, {data: data})
```

Then on the other page:

```
<form action = "PutTheExampleTableValuesHere.php" method = "post">
    <table ...>
        <thead>
            <?php foreach($_POST['data'] as $tr): ?>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach($tr as $td): ?>
                <td><?php echo $td ?></td>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </thead>
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Line Chart">
```

Comment: Hi, my table data will be integers and will be used as variables for to make a chart. That's the reason why I want to take each TD value individually.

Comment: Hi, @Panwen Wang. Thank you for your response! By reading the code to my student knowledge, it doesn't specify each table data as there is no specific ID provided? I would like to have each ID have an ID so I could call them specifically.

Comment: @SimoneWalter Actually, there are IDs implied, which are the indexes of the data in the `tmp` array and indexes of the `data` array. Because those data are stored in a fixed sequence in the arrays. Specifically, the indexes of `tmp` array refer to the indexes of `TD`s data in each `TR`, and the indexes of `data` refer to the indexes of `TR`s in the whole data posted. So on the other page, you can get those indexes by `<?php foreach($_POST['data'] as $i => $tr): ?>` and `<?php foreach($tr as $j => $td): ?>`

Answer (score 0):

with the $_POST logic is way more simpler than using javascript/ajax for this solution. Just put your data in some paragraph or similar and give it a name so you can access it from post from another external page that you call in "method" parameter in form.
example:

index.php:

```
  <form action="test.php" method="post">
  <table>
      <td>
          <div id="blah" name="blah" value="blah">BLAH</div>
      </td>
      <td>
          <div id="anoblah" name="anoblah" value="anotherblah">BLAH</div>
      </td>
      <input type="submit" id="test" name="test">
  </table>
  </form>
```

test.php

```
   <?php
        if(isset($_POST["test"]))
             echo "td1: ".$_POST["blah"]." td2: ".$_POST["anoblah"];


   ?>
```

Comment: Hello, @Orange Orange I can't get the values I tried to $_POST. I've encountered the problem at a different PHP page but I was able to fix it by moving it inside the <form> tag. But this time, it doesn't work.

Comment: if you post your code i would be glad to help you bro

Comment: please provide me with an e-mail so I could send it to you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use jquery to create an array (using input hidden) in the form structure. Then you can read it after the form submit, using $_POST variable.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $("form");
    $(".Testing td").each(function() {
      form.append('<input type="hidden" name="data[]" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');
    });
    form.submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

This will create an array from the TD values under class "Testing" that you can access over $_POST['data'] (type Array).

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
  foreach($_POST['data'] as $key=>$val) {
    echo $key.' = '.$val.'<br>';
  }
}
?>
```